# XSLT Missing content using value-of select

Tags: xml, xslt

input (I edited the input and output for better comprehension)

```
<csv>
<row>
    <id>a</id>
    <more>1</more>
    <stuff>123</stuff>
    <row>
        <id>1345</id>
        <stuff>dga</stuff>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>68968</id>
        <stuff>jkjh</stuff>
    </row
</row>
<row>
    <id>b</id>
    <more>12</more>
    <stuff>asdf</stuff>
    <row>
        <id>abhz</id>
        <stuff>ghjk</stuff>
    </row>
</row>
</csv>
```

desired output

```
<csv>
    <bamboo id="a" more="1">
        <p>123</p>
    </bamboo>
    <bamboo id="1345">
        <p>dga</p>
    </bamboo>
    <bamboo id="68968>
        <p>jkjh</p>
    <bamboo id="b" more="12">
        <p>asdf</p>
    </bamboo>
    <bamboo id="abhz">
        <pghjk</p>
    </bamboo>
</csv>
```

my try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="csv">
    <somelementshere>
        <text>
            <body>
                <div type="bamboopower">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </div>
            </body>
        </text>
    </somelementshere>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="row">

    <bamboo id="{id}" more="{1}">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="stuff"/></p>
    </bamboo>

    <bamboo id="row/row[comment_id]">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="row/row/stuff"/></p>
    </bamboo>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my output looks like:

```
            <bamboo id="a" more="1">
                <p>123</p>
            </bamboo>
            <bamboo id="">
                <p/>
            </bamboo>
            <bamboo id="b" more="12">
                <p>123</p>
            </bamboo>
            <bamboo id="">
                <p/>
            </bamboo>
```

As you can see, the contents from row/row are missing. What am I doing wrong? Also he does no run-through all row/row. There can be multiple child rows in row, I would need all.

(I need more details, my post consists mostly of code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is with this expression...

```
<xsl:value-of select="row/row/stuff"/>
```

You are currently matching a `row` element, so your expression will be relative to that, so by doing `row/row` you are looking for "grand-child" element called row. You really just do `<xsl:value-of select="row/stuff"/>`

This will be similar for the creation of the `id` attribute for the second `bamboo`. It should be this (I've replaced `comment_id` with `id` as there is no `comment_id` in your XML)

```
<bamboo id="{row/id}">
```

The second problem is that you code only assumes one child `row` element, where you might have multiple. For the creation of the second `bamboo`, and subsequent ones, you should wrap it in an `xsl:for-each`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="csv">
    <div type="bamboopower">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <bamboo id="{id}" more="{more}">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="stuff"/></p>
    </bamboo>

    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <bamboo id="{id}">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="stuff"/></p>
        </bamboo>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you could take this approach which will remove some duplicate coding:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="csv">
    <div type="bamboopower">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//row"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <bamboo id="{id}">
        <xsl:if test="more">
            <xsl:attribute name="more">
                <xsl:value-of select="more" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="stuff"/></p>
    </bamboo>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your first suggestion. It kinda works, but I only get the first row/row, not all. I will edit the question, so that the input is comprehensible.

Comment: Do you have multiple child rows per parent row?

Comment: I've amended my answer. The second suggestion would probably be the approach to take in this case.

Comment: That works great now! The first suggestion is easier to understand for me, so it is nice to have both for comparison and learning. Thanks!